# Restrict component access based on cognito usergroup

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, vuejs2, amazon-cognito

I am building a web application, in which I use **Vue 2** (2.6.11) and **AWS Cognito** for authentication. It all works fine (log in/out, display username, groupuser etc). I used this tutorial for it: https://sanaulla.info/2019/04/20/integrating-amazon-cognito-with-single-page-application-vue-js/

Now. My question is, how could I restrict the access to each Vue component based on my cognito usergroup?

Let's say I have two cognito usergroup: **admingrp** and **usergrp**, and inside my App.vue two components: **admin.vue** and **normal.vue** (there can be more in future). The admingrp users should be able to access both admin.vue and normal.vue, while the usergrp users can only access to normal.vue.

How could I reach this?

Answer (score 0):

The general answer to your question is that you need to test the groups in the JWT before allowing a user to access restricted parts of your site.

One easy way to do this is to use the Amplify UI [Authenticator component](https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/vue/components/authenticator) for the login flow. If your entire application is wrapped in this component, then every page will require login, and your application code will be able to rely on the `user` object that the component provides. This should contain the groups returned in the JWT, so you'll be able to test those to disallow access for non-admins on whichever pages you want.

[This blog post](https://isamatov.com/react-permissions-and-roles/) describes a clean pattern you can use for this, although it may be a bit more involved than you need.